# Get the distorted/encrypted image from encrypted data bytes of an image

Tags: c#, encryption

I have encrypted the data bytes of an image file (.jpeg/.png) using Simplified DES. But after encryption, the image file cannot be reconverted to an image as it loses it's original file structure. Is there any way by which I can use these encrypted data bytes to convert to an image file? Here is a glimpse of my C# code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the RGB/GRAY/BINARY image path: ");
        string path = Console.ReadLine();
        byte []arrayPT = Conversion.Convert.ImageToBinary(path); // Get the binary data             
        byte []arrayCT = new byte[arrayPT.Length];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (byte element in arrayPT)
        {
            arrayCT[i] = ob.Encrypt(element); 
        /* I want to use the contents of the arrayCT[] and convert to an image */
            Console.Write("{0}", arrayCT[i]);
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Are you encrypting the pixels and then saving the file as JPEG? That will never work because JPEG is a lossy compression, it will alter the pixels a little bit, and you won't be able to decrypt that. It should work with PNG though. But it cannot be diagnosed if we don't see the whole code.

Comment: I think you should encrypt the whole byte array in a single `.Encrypt` call.  Encrypting one byte at a time does not seem to be a good approach.

Comment: @fejesjoco encryption and decryption both works fine. For getting the original image arrayCT[] is decrypted and reconverted to image using instance of MemoryStream class.

Comment: @wdosanjos - yes, i haven't still optimized the algorithm. Thanks for your review :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current approach you are encrypting the image header along with the contents, it will not be considered an image anymore.

If you do not need to hide the fact that it is an image nor its width×height, the approach I would take is the following:

1. Get the original image into a Bitmap object
2. This should give you access to the decompressed image as byte array (Bitmapdata)
3. Encrypt the byte array
4. Create a new Bitmap object with the same width and height of the original
5. Import the encrypted bytes into the new Bitmap bytes
6. Save the image in a new file with the same format as the input image

Check [Bitmapdata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a way to work with the image bytes efficiently.